# hook_field_access does not deny access

Tags: entities, hooks, users

I've been trying to use hook_field_access to deny access to fields under a certain bundle. However it does not work as intended.

This is the code

```
function applx_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account){
    return FALSE;
}
```

All the examples work somewhat like this, but im not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Looks fine to me. It's good to double-check the basics: have you enabled the module and cleared all caches?!

Comment: Yes, i added a dpm($field); in the method to confirm it is being called.

Comment: I'm trying to deny access to certain administrators as well, as they will have permissions individually - this is taken care of already by user permissions module.

Comment: That's strange. I just pasted your hook into a module and tested it, and it denied view and edit access as expected. Have you posted the full `hook_field_access()`?

Comment: It only has one tiny change. You can see the entire .module file here
http://notey.it/n/dDY0

Comment: Still looks fine to me. I take it from the `dpm()` condition that you're testing it on the edit form? I can only guess that some other module is playing around with the form and changing/overwriting the access. Are there any modules you're using that might match that description? If so, try disabling them and see if it helps. What kind of entity are you editing? I'd start debugging by using a `hook_form_alter()` on the entity edit form to double-check the `#access` property of the field elements (they should all be set to `FALSE`).

Comment: Could you just confirm what exactly the _actual_ behaviour is at the moment? I've been assuming that instead of all the fields being hidden, all the fields are visible: is that correct?

Comment: im editing a node entity, the bundle is created by my module on enable. The current behavior is that, regardless of the field_access_hook returning false, it renders the field edit form and changes are being made successfully on submission.

Comment: Thanks. The code definitely works; I've tested it on a node edit form. So there has to be something local to your site causing the problem. I've suggested above double-checking the node form array; you can also try stepping through `field_attach_form()`. But really there's no way to debug the problem from the information provided, it's something you're going to have to track down yourself I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35738/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-andy).